# How to store a route in linked lists

Tags: c, loops, linked-list, coordinates

I want to make a route of coordinates from a text (stdin) where the input will be an undetermined amount of coordinates eg

```
[0,1]
[1,1]
[1,2]
.
.
.
```

So I want to make a while loop that scans a coordinate and adds it to a linked list until its gone through all the coordinates. Only problem is I have no idea where to start on doing that as I cant think of how to make a linked list with x and y coordinates. Any help with getting me on the right track would be greatly appreciated, cheers.

Comment: You may start by figuring out what data you need in each node of the linked list.

Comment: In the general examples a linked list has only one parameter e.g. `int val` But you can have as many parameters as you like in the list e.g.`typedef struct node { int x, int y, struct node * next};`

Comment: Oh right  Rishikesh Raje, I didn't realise it would be that simple, cheers

Answer (score 0):

While most tutorial examples of linked lists use only one "payload" member:

```
struct Node {
  int value;
  struct Node* next;
}
```

there is nothing stopping you from adding more:

```
struct Node {
  int x;
  int y;
  struct Node* next;
}
```

You may also want to group the payload members to keep them separated from the list infrastructure:

```
struct Node {
  struct {
    int x;
    int y;
  } coord;
  struct Node* next;
}
```